# $\lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{1}{N+1}\sum_{n=0}^N f_n=\lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{1}{N+1}\sum_{n=0}^N f_{n+m}$ for any $f_n$ and $m\in \mathbb N$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, stochastic-analysis

> Show that $\lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{1}{N+1}\sum_{n=0}^N f_n=\lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{1}{N+1}\sum_{n=0}^N f_{n+m}$ for any
>   $f_n$ and $m\in \mathbb N$, where the limit exists.

Can I split the sum? For example can I:

$$\lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{1}{N+1}\sum_{n=0}^N f_{n+m}$$
$$=\lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{1}{N+1}(\sum_{n=0}^N f_{m} + \sum_{n=0}^N f_{n})$$

and since I'm taking a finite $m \Rightarrow \lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{1}{N+1}\sum_{n=0}^N f_m=0$

Comment: What is the logic for the splitting? What makes you think that you can split it in this way?

Comment: @SchrodingersCat I don't know, I kind of see that if I take $\lim_{n\to \infty} n$ it should be the same as $\lim_{n\to \infty} n+m$

Comment: But you don't know the nature of $f$. So you cannot make such a claim. It might not be linear like $n$.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat I know that the limit of $f$ exists (I'm not sure if it's the limit of the sum or the sequence itself, it's not so clear) , so I assumed $f$ is either constant or decreasing to 0 (if it's the sum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
$$
g_N=\frac{1}{N+1}\sum_{n=0}^N f_n
$$
which is by assumption a convergent sequence.

Then
$$
\sum_{n=0}^Nf_{m+n}=(m+N+1)g_{m+N}-mg_{m-1}
$$
which allows to apply standard sequence convergence rules to conclude the claim.